# PythonEngine.Initialize() fails without any error message

Tags: c#, python, .net, python-2.7, python.net

I am trying to embed Python in a C#-application but I cannot seem to get it to work. 
My code is

```
using System;
using Python.Runtime;

namespace NLP.Python
{
   public class PythonRumtime
   {
       public PythonRuntime()
    {
       //Location of python installation
       PythonEngine.PythonHome = "C:\\Python27";
       PythonEngine.Initialize();
     }
    }
 }
```

When I try to create an instance of this class, the code fails without any errors when invoking PythonEngine.Initialize()
I have already added a reference to the dll-file Python.Runtime that was installed with pythonnet.

I have no idea what else to do.

I have installed pythonnet-2.1.0 via pip on a Windows 64-bit machine with a 32-bit installation of Python 2.7.11.

EDIT It appears that the error occurs at at call to Py_Initialize() in Python.Runtime.dll. 
According to https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html "There is no return value; it is a fatal error if the initialization fails."

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but you need to either change the `PythonHome` string to @"C:\Python27" or "C:\\Python27".  You have to escape the `\\`.

Comment: @pstrjds Sorry, that was a formatting error when pasting my code. I have edited my question

Comment: If there are no errors, how do you know it fails?

Comment: Well, when I run my test (just creating an instance) there is a message that the process failed unexpectedly. Which isn't that informative.

Comment: What message? What pops it up? Is it an unhandled exception, output from the VSTest runner? Do you get the option to debug anything? You'll need to dig deeper. Almost certainly, there's something inside trying to communicate with you about the failure, you'll just need to reach it.

Comment: I run the test in VS from the Test Explorer and it print the message "The active Test Run was aborted because the execution process exited unexpectedly" in the Output window. I also tried to build Python.Runtime.DLL from the source code on github. Stepping though the code in Debug-mode revealed that this failure is caused at a call to Py_Initialize()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in python.org official windows installer for python 2.7.11 32-bit:

https://bugs.python.org/issue25824

Try Anaconda, maybe WinPython or python 2.7.10.

Comment: This, combined with removing the line `PythonEngine.PythonHome = "C:\\Python27";` did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: there is open issue with setting pythonhome or pythonpath: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/pull/186